# How do I make the WindowsFormsHost transparent?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

I am using `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost` in my WPF application. The `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost` is a parent of the `Panel` control, and I am rendering this `Panel` to show the live camera image from the web-cam.

How do I make it transparent, so that the end user is not able to see the web-cam on the User interface?

Comment: Please, provide more detail, and show relevant code as it will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Transaparency can not apply to WindowsFormsHost.
So, you should find another alternative. You can set it visibility.